# Quest for Multi-Development Web Platforms: Titanium, OpenLaszlo or others if any ? Which to prefer?

Tags: language-agnostic

In my quest for Multidevelopement Web Platforms (Desktop Browser and Mobile), I have encountered only 2 :

- Titanium
- Openlaszlo

Only two. So are there any others ?

I have looked at Titanium, seems very promising but I wasn't even able to create a project as It crashed on my windows 7 PC.

As for Openlaszlo I heard about it years ago; OpenLaszlo can generate both flash and html.  I wasn't really interested until now as I didn't really have any real need for being multiplatform. Flash alone could suffice with Web Desktop.

Did you try any of them ?

I'm looking for .NET and Java.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC is what you would call a "multi-development platform."  The [Mobile Browser Definition File](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixMobileWebSitesWithASPNETMVCAndTheMobileBrowserDefinitionFile.aspx) is ideal for customizing behavior across different mobile phone models.

Comment: ASP.NET is a very good platform. I didn't look at ASP.NET MVC yet but I'm pleased to learn from you that it could also do mobile.

But I also need the same thing for Java platform. Did SUN create something equivalent to ASP.NET MVC for mobile ?